# How to determine if one of multiple object has certain class?

Tags: jquery, css

I have HTML lets say like:

```
<ul>
<li class="test"></li>
<li class="test"></li>
<li class="test"></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Now how can I test if there's one or more `li` that has class `test`?

`$("li").hasClass("test");` doesn't seem to do the job...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($("li.test").length > 0) {
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Now how can I test if there's one or more `li` that has class `test`?

`$("li.test").size() > 0` means there is at least one `li` that has the class `test`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `li` selected you could use `.is(".test")`

If you want to know how many have that class you can do `$("li.test").length`